# This page didn't load Google Maps correctly

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I want to track drivers from Taxi App on the back end  web page to tracking drivers map it's give this error

> This page didn't load Google Maps correctly. See the JavaScript console for technical details.

code for page is :

```
    <?php 
require_once('../includes/config.php');
require_once('../includes/database.class.php');
$db= new database($pdo);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 
<head> 
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<title>map</title> 
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png",
new google.maps.Size(32, 32), new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
new google.maps.Point(16, 16));
var center = null;
var map = null;
var currentPopup;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
 function addMarker(lat, lng, info ) {
 var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
bounds.extend(pt);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: pt,
 icon: icon, 
map: map,
 });
var popup = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
});
 popup.setContent(info);
 popup.open(map, marker);
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
 if (currentPopup != null) {
currentPopup.close();
currentPopup = null;
}
popup.open(map, marker);
currentPopup = popup;
});
google.maps.event.addListener(popup, "closeclick", function() {
map.panTo(center);
currentPopup = null;
 });
}
function initMap() {
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
 zoom: 1,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
mapTypeControl: false,
mapTypeControlOptions: {
style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR
},
navigationControl: true,
navigationControlOptions: {
style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
}
});
<?php  
$db->mapOffers();
?>
center = bounds.getCenter();
 map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
</script>
<style>
 #map{
    border:#CCC thin solid;
    height: 480px;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    padding: 0px
  }
</style>
</head> 
<body onload="initMap()" style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;" class="home"> 
<?php 
//  $db->mapOffers();
?>
<div id="map"></div>
</body> 
</html>
```

can you help me

Comment: So what does the console say?

Comment: Can we see the php codes return value.You have defined addMarker() method but never called in the script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include a key in the google map api script

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

You can register for the key : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

As of June 22, 2016 Google Maps V3 no longer support keyless access (any request that doesn't include an API key).