# Google Maps React - This page cannot load google maps correctly

Tags: reactjs, api, maps, developer-console

I'm sure this question has been asked a million times before, I have searched every answer on the internet and i'm still having no luck.

The error is actually this - `You must enable Billing on the Google Cloud Project at 
 https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/billing/enable Learn more at 
 https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started` when viewing in the browser console.

I have tried several different things such as:

1) Using our internal company API key which is used within our prod app.

2) Creating my own personal account via the Google Dev Console, generating an API Key and adding my own personal card details so that billing is `enabled`.

I have also consulted these different pages:

1) [This page didn't load Google Maps correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39071783/this-page-didnt-load-google-maps-correctly)

2) [Enable Billing on the Google Cloud Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58268679/enable-billing-on-the-google-cloud-project)

3) https://www.embedgooglemap.co.uk/fixed-this-page-cant-load-google-maps-correctly-error/

I have waited to 5/10 mins as suggested on some of the posts, I have regenerated my keys, I have ensured that the API key is linked to the billed account.

However, NOTHING is working! I am finding this highly frustrating as i've done this lots of times before.

The way I am using my key is as follows:

```
import { withGoogleMap, GoogleMap, withScriptjs, InfoWindow, Marker } from "react-google-maps";
import Geocode from "react-geocode";
import Autocomplete from 'react-google-autocomplete';
Geocode.setApiKey("API-KEY-HERE");
Geocode.enableDebug();
```

Does anyone know where I am going wrong with this? As i have been looking into this for hours now and cannot figure it out!

Thanks!

Comment: So do you have an issue with the `react-google-maps` Map - the actual google map you want to render on the page - or do you have an issue with `react-geocode`? If you have an issue with the actual map from `react-google-maps`, the code where you render the map would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I had a hardcoded API key somewhere else in my file. Swapping that out for my proper API key has worked :)